# Deploy ADFS 2.0 login page to ADFS 3.0?

Tags: adfs, adfs2.0

I have set up a ADFS 3.0 server on Windows Server 2012 R2.
To satisfy the requirement, I need to customize the default login page (not only the UI, but the validation logic).
Since ADFS 3.0 is not allow me to customize the login page, I decide to write the login page myself.

I decide to extract the source code of ADFS 2.0 login page, and deploy it to IIS as my new login page. Is it possible?

Or please provide some information on customizing the ADFS 3.0 login page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No because ADFS 3.0 no longer uses IIS.

Also the page is locked down - there are some PowerShell commands to do simple things.

To configure the login page refer: [Handling Expired Passwords in AD FS 2012 R2](http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2014/5/27/handling-expired-passwords-in-ad-fs-2012-r2.html)

**Update:** This question comes up so many times that I wrote it up.

Refer: [ADFS : Customising the screen for ADFS 2012 R2 or ADFS 3.0 or ADFS 2.2](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2014/05/adfs-customising-screen-for-adfs-2012.html)

Comment: You make my life easier. I would like to vote up Hundreds time if I can.